# Use of undeclared type 'T' when declared array of any type in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground, generics

I'm trying to declare a property with an array of any type T. But I'm getting compiler error - Use of undeclared type 'T'. Below is the class that I created with 2 properties.

```
class Product {
 var productName: String;
 var items: Array<T>
}
```

Please let me know how to declare an array of any type using Generics in Swift. I've tried the below options:

```
{
var items: Array<T>;
var items = Array<T>();
var items = [T]();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to define the generic type in the class declaration:

```
class Product<T> {
    var productName: String;
    var items: Array<T>
}
```

Of course, since the class has uninitialized non optional variables, you have to either initialize them inline:

```
class Product<T> {
    var productName: String = ""
    var items: Array<T> = Array<T>()
}
```

make them optionals:

```
class Product<T> {
    var productName: String?
    var items: Array<T>?
}
```

define an initializer:

```
class Product<T> {
    var productName: String
    var items: Array<T>

    init(productName: String, items: Array<T>) {
        self.productName = productName
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

or any combination of them.

Note that the trailing semicolon is not required in swift, unless you put more than one statement in the same line

Comment: How would we do the equivalent for extension functions?

Answer (score -1):

I'm addressing the error in general.

I was getting the the following errors for a different reason.

**Error1**

> cannot specialize non-generic type 'Person'

**Error2**

> use of undeclared type 'T'

for making a slightly different mistake:

```
protocol Person{
    associatedtype language
    func write(_ language: language)
    func read(_ language: language)
}
```

I was conforming to it like this:

```
struct American: Person<T>{
    func read(_ language: T) {

    }
    func write(_ language: T) {

    }
}
```

But I needed to conform like this instead.

```
struct American<T> : Person{
    func read(_ language: T) {

    }
    func write(_ language: T) {

    }
}
```